# Provisioning customer accounts with Terraform (workspaces, Modules, ?) Best Practice?

Tags: module, workspace, terraform

I have the need to create and manage multiple customer environments in AWS and I'm wanting to leverage Terraform to deploy all of the necessary resources.  Each customer environment is basically the same with the exception of the URL they use to access one of the servers.

I have put together a Terraform configuration that deploys all of the resources for a given customer.  BUT... How do I take that same configuration and apply it to the next customer without copying the entire Terraform directory and duplicating that for every customer. (I could have 100's of these)

I've heard workspaces and modules or both.  Anyone seen a best-practice article out there on this?

Thx

Comment: Not `workspaces`, definitely modules as per Farid's answer. The docs specifically recommend not using workspaces for environments or system decomposition. They are for experiments or things like that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should [modulerize your code](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html), then you can easily reuse that module(from a git repository) with different variables to be used for that customer. In this case for each customer, you will end up with only a file that configures the main module.

Have one directory for each customer, with a terraform file that loads up the module(s) and configures it. If you use `terraform apply` in that directory then the state will also be in that directory. To make sure your team can also deploy and make changes it is suggested to use a [backend](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/index.html) such as S3, so the state will be written there. Note that you have to configure a backend for each customer in their respective directory. Make sure the backend for each customer don't clash(For example use a different path in S3).

Nicki Watt gave a good presentation on this. You can view the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgzgVm7Sqlk) and slides at [here](https://www.slideshare.net/opencredo/hashidays-london-2017-evolving-your-infrastructure-with-terraform-by-nicki-watt).

Comment: So, there is some metadata associated with a given customer that's unique and I can see how modulerizing my code will facilitate managing that data, but how do I manage the state of each customer?  Manually construct a filesystem to maintain all customers?

Comment: @user4109728 I updated the answer. Hopefully I answered your questions.

Comment: That does help clarify things.  I've been working on this today and have come to the same "not so nice" conclusion.  It appears that although an S3 backend helps with state, it does nothing for a specific customer configuration.  That's still gonna need a repo to maintain.  :(  Thanks though!

Comment: I've had a chance to work on this a bit more and I think I've got it.  Everything is a module now and I'm able to deploy from that module for multiple customers.  Here's what I did... Create the "master" terraform config and check it into git (Master).  Then for each customer, I check out master and create a branch for each customer, modify the terraform config, and check it back in.  See any holes in that approach?  Thanks!  Your comments helped a lot!

Comment: @user4109728 That also works I guess. I guess as long the repo, doesn't contain the modules codes, should be fine. Because if it does, then each updating the modules in each branch would be a pain. In your approach best would be to have modules in separate git repo(s).

Comment: Can you create the S3 bucket with terraform that is used as the remote backend?

Comment: @davos you certainly can, but in a different terraform stack.

Comment: And you know my next question, how do you create the s3 backend for that different stack? I assume you just have to manually create one at some point. It's ~~turtles~~ s3 buckets all the way down

Comment: That's true. What would be easy to do if have a lot of terraform stacks, or you create environments frequently is to just automate the s3 bucket creation with a script.

Comment: This approach is fine, but then say you make a change in a module and want to TF reapply for each customer stack.  Is there any way to make this nicer than some adhoc script to loop over the customer directories and apply the config?

Comment: In practice I've seen there'd a be CI pipeline for each stack, which detects changes and makes a plan when there's a change and if approved by someone then it'd applies. Someone still has to manually approve the plan, because you wouldn't want things to accidentally go haywire.