# How to use dynamic resource names in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I would like to use the same terraform template for several dev and production environments.

My approach: 
As I understand it, the resource name needs to be unique, and terraform stores the state of the resource internally. I therefore tried to use variables for the resource names - but it seems to be not supported. I get an error message:

```
$ terraform plan
var.env1
  Enter a value: abc

Error asking for user input: Error parsing address 'aws_sqs_queue.SqsIntegrationOrderIn${var.env1}': invalid resource address "aws_sqs_queue.SqsIntegrationOrderIn${var.env1}"
```

My terraform template:

```
variable "env1" {}

provider "aws" {
        region = "ap-southeast-2"
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "SqsIntegrationOrderIn${var.env1}" {
        name = "Integration_Order_In__${var.env1}"
        message_retention_seconds = 86400
        receive_wait_time_seconds = 5
}
```

I think, either my approach is wrong, or the syntax. Any ideas?

Comment: manage with terraform modules, you needn't dynamicly redefine the resource name.

Comment: You should mark Farid's answer as correct. The similar question linked to in that answer is spot on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend using a different [workspace](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html) for each environment. This allows you to specify your configuration like this:

```
variable "env1" {}

provider "aws" {
        region = "ap-southeast-2"
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "SqsIntegrationOrderIn" {
        name = "Integration_Order_In__${var.env1}"
        message_retention_seconds = 86400
        receive_wait_time_seconds = 5
}
```

Make sure to make the name of the "aws_sqs_queue" resource depending on the environment (e.g. by including it in the name) to avoid name conflicts in AWS.

Comment: The docs specifically say that `workspaces` are "not a suitable tool for system decomposition" and , regarding "different development stages (e.g. staging vs. production)" it is "not a suitable isolation mechanism" see  https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html#when-to-use-multiple-workspaces Instead, you should use modules and import them into different terraform init directories for dev, staging, prod etc and do special enviroment things in those interfaces. Best practice is also using different AWS accounts, so name conflicts aren't an issue.

Answer (score 12):

You can't interpolate inside the resource name. Instead what you should do is as [@BMW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498256/bmw) have mentioned in the comments, you should make a terraform module that contains that `SqsIntegrationOrderIn` inside and takes `env` variable. Then you can use the module twice, and they simply won't clash. You can also have a look at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46266357/774086) I answered.

Comment: Going further, the OP should use different AWS Accounts for different environments then name clashes are not a thing.

Comment: Using separate accounts is the way to go. Agreed and easy to implement using AWS organizations.

Comment: @Davos can you point at a good example of this (cross) account deployment setup? I am using the .aws/config and ./aws/credentials entries of another account, and specifying `AWS_PROFILE=dev_admin` for example, but resource owners are still showing as the main org's Management Account #.  I've had no luck with the `provider` "profile" either...

Comment: @d8aninja Sounds like a new question and not enough info to give you a decent answer. You can set up roles in different accounts and _assume_ them, or cross-account roles or different users in different accounts. This https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/organize-configuration describes the different setups. Check out `aws_caller_identity`, and also the `assume_role` attribute of the aws provider, and https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#allowed_account_ids

Comment: @Davos can you post your suggestions here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69508090/are-there-any-good-examples-of-cross-account-deployments-using-the-same-terrafor